github action checking changes files in Pull request - what is the best way of checking this?
I'm setting up a GitHub Actions workflow to perform validation checks on new files added when a new PR is created. Due to company policies, I can only use verified GitHub Actions, so I aim to rely on Git commands for these checks.
I have set up the following in my GitHub action, which gives me the changes from my last commit and main:
 .
 .
 . 
  steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
          fetch-depth: 0
    

      - name: Run process and validate script
        id: changes
        run: |
         echo "git show --name-only --format=  HEAD"

Ideally, I would like to run git diff main --name-only, but this gives me the following error when running with the GitHub action:
fatal: ambiguous argument 'main': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.

It works fine on my local computer since I have the main there, but when running my GitHub action, I only pull my PR and not the main. I could pull the main down as well, but I don't feel that this is a good solution.
Here is what that could look like:
   steps:
      - name: Checkout PR branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
          fetch-depth: 0  # Fetch all history for branches and tags

      - name: Fetch main branch
        run: |
          git fetch origin main:main  # Fetch main branch as a local branch called main

      - name: Run process and validate script
        run: |
          # Now you can successfully run git diff between the PR branch and main
          git diff main --name-only

Any suggestions as to what is the preferred option here?

git fetch --depth=1 origin main:main to fetch exactly one commit, the one that's pointed to by main

thanks for the feedback @phd, but the problem is that i would have to run git pull main first to be able to do this right?

No, why? And again, pull accepts --depth: git pull --depth=1 origin main

That is create! i will test this. thank you!

Please be warned that if main is not the current branch git pull origin main fetches the branch and then merges it into the current.
